# Image that fills scrollview view but does not scrunch the image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview, and it looks good, but whenever I try to fix the problem of the image being scrunched, I can not figure it out, I tried scaleAspectFill, but that did not work. If you can help me fix the image to not scrunch but take up the whole view, that would be great, here is a screenshot to help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2myM.jpg

Comment: You should post your code in text here but not an image.

Comment: Are you sure your image isn't like that? Cause setting aspect fill ought to have worked properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Somehow, this didn't work for me today. My ImageView is circular...idk

Answer (score 0):

Change this code:

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

into this:

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```